# Install a software throe wine on ntfs partition

Tags: wine, ntfs, ext4

I have a question I want to install windows software, but I do not have enough space on ext4 partition, so if I install the software on ntfs directory will the software run as it would run on ext/home partition ?? or there will be some limitations ??